# ValueError: Input array has fewer dimensions than the specified axes

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, wavelet, haar-wavelet, dwt

I was trying to apply discrete wavelet transform on 2D matrix of size (23x7680) but I get this error `ValueError: Input array has fewer dimensions than the specified axes`.

Any help would be appreciated.

**code**:

```
data=np.random.rand(23,7680)
coeffs = pywt.dwt2(data, 'haar')
cA, (cH, cV, cD) = coeffs
```

Comment: The identical code works for me.

Comment: @JussiNurminen when I am working on my data I get the above error I don't know why

Comment: Are you sure? Also, what's your version of PyWaveLets?

Comment: @JussiNurminen yes I am sure. version (1.16.5)

Comment: At least with 1.19.1 I don't get this problem. So maybe try to upgrade?

Comment: @JussiNurminen Also working with me when I run the above code on version (1.16.5) but when i work on my dataset i get the above error. I don't know why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222184/discussion-between-jussi-nurminen-and-edayildiz).